# More advanced logic while filtering a view? SP2013

Tags: 2013, column, filter, library, metadata

I am attempting to filter a document library view in SP2013 but I have three things I need to filter on and I don't know if I can perform the logic desired. I want this view to only show documents with logic as follows:

((DocumentType = Dashboard) OR (DocumentType = Supporting Detail)) AND (Filter By Week >= [Today])

DocumentType is a column that allows for four meta fields: Dashboard, Supporting Detail, Documentation, or Meeting Materials.

Filter By Week is a column that uses a formula to only show update documents within the past week from today.

The goal is to have a view that will only show dashboard or supporting detail document types that are new within the week. The problem is I haven't found out how to do this with SP2013's logic. Maybe I can enter multiple meta tags somehow? (As in the below picture is it possible to put "Dashboard OR Supporting Detail" in that first column filter?)

[image]

If you have any ideas or solutions it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you create a calculated column with your condition and filter by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The View Filter can **not** do

```
(x OR y) AND z
```

it does:

```
x OR y AND z
```

So you have to move part of the logic into a Boolean type Calculated Column *DocumentTypeFilter*

```
=OR( [DocumentType]="Dashboard" , [DocumentType]="Supporting Detail" )
```

And use *DocumentTypeFilter*=True in the View Filter

You can **not** use [Today] in a Calculated Column, because those Formulas are only updated when anything in the List Item changes (which could have been prior to Today)
So the the [Today] comparison remains in your View Filter.

Note that you can do Calculations in the View Filter, no need for a separate [Filter By Week] Calculation if you use

Modified *greater than or equal* **[Today]-7**

Comment: Awesome. I was looking at something that was similar to that here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/850983b1-5570-4f0a-bc43-0cee8cbbb130/how-to-set-up-complex-filters-in-views?forum=sharepointadminlegacy but it was way over complicated. The [Today] part isn't used in that other calculated column's formula (it's =Modified+6) thanks for the help!

Comment: I didn't know I could just do that calculation in the View Filter - gave me an error so I probably just used the wrong syntax when I tried. Thanks for the useful information!